# Menu drawer toggle (slide up/down)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple menu and from it, i am using jQuery to toggle visibility of few DIV's.
Code is pretty straightforward, like bellow, and if i am not asking too much, i could use some help with additional functionalities.

```
<div id="one" class="navLinks"> content 1 </div>
<div id="two" class="navLinks"> content 2 </div>
<div id="three" class="navLinks"> content 3 </div>
<div class="nav">
    <nav>
       <a href="#one">1</a>
       <a href="#two">2</a>
       <a href="#three">3</a>
        <a href="http://google.com">Normal Link</a>
    </nav>
</div>

$('nav a').click(function() {
  $('.navLinks').hide();
      $(this.getAttribute('href')).slideToggle('slow')
});
```

So, currently, if the user click on the link, a div will slide from the top, but except that, i would need 2 more things.

If user opens, lets say link no.2, and after that, he wants to close it by clicking on the same  link, div should slide up (instead of down like it currently does).

Similiar to this, if the user opens link no2, and after that wants to open link no1, after the click, that div would need to slide up and be shown.

I know i am asking too much, but any help would be greately appreciated.

FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/4rfYB/38/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using jQuery's [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude the requested element from those being hidden.
That way, you can hide all content areas that are *not* the requested one.

I've also used `slideUp('slow')` instead of `hide()`, purely for stylistic reasons.

```js
$('nav a').click(function() {
  var $requested = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
  $('.navLinks').not($requested).slideUp('slow');
  $requested.slideToggle('slow')
});
```

```css
.navLinks {
  display: none;
  color: white;
}
div#one {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}
div#two {
  background: blue;
  height: 80px;
}
div#three {
  background: black;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <nav>
    <a href="#one">1</a>
    <a href="#two">2</a>
    <a href="#three">3</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="one" class="navLinks">content 1</div>
<div id="two" class="navLinks">content 2</div>
<div id="three" class="navLinks">content 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('nav a').click(function() {
  $(this.getAttribute('href')).toggleClass('open').slideToggle('slow',function() {
      $(this).siblings('.open').slideToggle('slow').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4rfYB/39/